# Blurry nebulae in Eevee

Tags: rendering, node-editor, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm trying to render a scene in which I have nebulaes made from volumetrics.

EDIT : I forgot to mention that it is a "flythrough" scene, the camera is flying through 4 successive volumetrics cubes. So the camera is in the smoke itself !

I'm rendering with Eevee, and rendering gives me blurry Nebulaes :
[image]

Could it be a nebulae density problem ? Or is it really an issue with my render settings, and/or camera settings ? As you can see, I also have a particle system here (some kind of asteroïds) and it does not seem to suffer from this blurry effect...

Here's the node setup, the camera settings, and the render settings (with a small amount of samples but even doubling or tripling it doesn't fix the issue) :

Nebulae Node Setup
[image: Nebulae Node Setup]

Camera settings
[image: Camera settings]

Eevee Settings
[image: Eevee Settings]

Sorry for the length of this post, I didn't find any "spoiler" box, and I don't know how I am supposed to resize the images.

Comment: How does it render in Cycles? That might give an indication as to whether it's a problem with your volume or whether it's the Eevee render settings. You could try increasing Samples in the Volumetrics Eevee settings - or if your volume doesn't start until quite a distance into your scene, try increasing the Volumetrics 'Start' until it just starts clipping (and make sure 'End' is no more than the furthest distance of the volume).

Comment: Is depth of field enabled?

Comment: That looks awesome. Nut sure what's blurred, exactly, but if you mean the blurs around the edges, that looks like the camera itself is in the smoke (hyad this problem today. actually :-) ). Move the camera, or limit how far the volume extends (check out Geometry -> position and Vector Math -Distance)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your attention
First, I forgot to say that this is a "flythrough" scene. So I have multiple volumetric cubes and a camera flying through them. I'll edit the initial post.

Comment: @Rich Sedman : I tried to increase the volumetric samples, it does not have any effect on the "blurriness" of the render, same for the volumetric distance (it is set to be visible from the camera to the end of each volumetric cube).
I tried to render this with Cycles, but renders takes forever (even with RTX GPU and Optix activated) and it is simply awful to watch, as volumetrics scenes (smokes and vol lighting) seems to work very differently between both rendering engines :/ Here's an example with 512 samples, denoising activated and 12 light boucing in Cycles : shorturl.at/imsHN

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Nop, it is set to 100px as default in Eevee, and it is turned of in the camera settings. My first idea was to make the camera focus on an empty, but for some reason it does not work... maybe it is part of the problem ? There's another post in which the issue seems to be the same as mine on blenderartists (no answer) : https://blenderartists.org/t/eevee-dof-not-registering-depth-in-my-render/1189402

Comment: @ZargulTheWIzard Thanks :) As said in my first comment it is a flythrough scene, so... yeah the camera is in the smoke as it is flying through the volumetric cubes :(
I'll try to move the camera to see if it solves the issue, but I really need it to fly through my multiple volumetric cubes :(
Also, where can I find this setting you suggested me to modify ? (Geometry -> position and Vector Math -Distance)
Again, thanks for your help ! (both of you)

Comment: Finally, I tried to highlight the edges of my nebulaes thanks to a color ramp and a subtrack node just before the density input of  the Principled Volume BSDF. That way I can have sharpy edges, but it is not what I want, and it is not fixing the blurry issue. See here : https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2020/11/25/201125124312530576.png

Comment: maybe its the bloom, turn it a lil down

Comment: The "setting" thing was nodes in the shader. :P Given the flythrough requirement, I recommend using a vector math node to calculate the cube's distance from the camera, and then use math to make the density drop to zero when the camera enters.

Comment: But first, try turning off the bloom.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the delay, I had to take a break on this project. I'll make separated answers so that it is easier for you to follow the topic.
BLOOM (@Alex bries @ZargulTheWizard) So I tried to render disabling Bloom, then SSR, then AO, and it makes litteraly no difference on the final result. :/

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Ok, maybe I don't understand what you're saying but, as it is a flythrough scene, my camera actually fly through those cubes and at that time I need density :/
Does your answer suggest that I can't avoid this blurry render flying through a volumetric node setup? I tried to render one of my nebulae cubes on a reasonable distance from the camera with a focus on this nebulae. Aaaaaand it gave me this : https://nsa40.casimages.com/img/2020/12/09/201209103323518447.png
To me it's doesnt change that much, is it ? haaalp hahaha

Comment: Thx. That is weird. In the additional image, the camera is completely outside of all volumetrics, confirm? PLS upload the blend file, this could be a million things.

Comment: Try turning off bloom.

Comment: Hey @ZargulTheWizard ! As stated earlier, I tried to disable Bloom, it changed nothing :/
I'll give you a blend file, I just need to append those nebulaes to a new file, because my main project will probably be used for commercial purposes. I'll do it in the coming hours
And again, thanks for your help !

Comment: and yeah, in the last image linked, the camera is completely outside of any mesh or volumetrics

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard here is a simplified blend file : https://we.tl/t-IJHvuHKxff
And again, thank you !

Comment: Thx. Looked at the file, and it seems to be just normal EEVEE rendering. You may not be able to improve these results with EEVEE>

Comment: Yes that was my conclusion too. :( I'll deal with this for the moment... Sorry for the inconvenience, it's been a while since you're trying to help me on this